# How to get folder lower_path in the Dropbox API by it's shared link URL?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a problem with getting folder path by it's shared link. I'm using `/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata` endpoint of API.
For example I have already a folder with a path "**/Test**" and name "**Test**", where I'm an owner. Another user of my working group created a folder with  a path "**/Test**" and name "**Test**". Also this user assigned me as folder owner and created shared link
to newly created folder.

Then I'm getting this link and passed it to the `/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata endpoint` (in "url" parameter) to get path of this folder that this user have created. But in response there is no "path_lower" field. This field should be always available in the DropBox API response in case if folder is awailable for the API caller ([link to Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata))

How can I get folder lower_path by it's shared link url only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [the /2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata) is slightly misleading/inaccurate. The `path_lower` field will actually only be returned if the access token being used is for the same account that owns the shared link itself. I'll ask the team to fix that up.

In your case, it the link was created by the other user, so when you call with your own access token, `path_lower` isn't returned.